# SSRS - Barchart with 3 values - (One bar should highlight 2 values and remaining one on other bar)

Tags: reporting-services, charts

I am trying to make a bar chart to represent the logging hours of an employee. is it possible through SSRS ??

[image]

Here is a sample database structure and values , I want the "Name" in X axis and Y axis can be the Hours.

[image]

Comment: show some sample data from your dataset and update your screenshot to show the expected results from that sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One workaround is creating a cross join in your query to create a dummy grouping for the stacked bar chart.

My sample Dataset:

```
SELECT 
    name,
    CASE WHEN chartgroup = 1 THEN estimated END AS estimated,
    CASE WHEN chartgroup = 2 THEN actual END AS actual,
    CASE WHEN chartgroup = 1 THEN diff END AS diff,
    chartgroup

FROM (
    select 'alan' as name, 120 as 'estimated', 138 as 'actual',  50 as diff 
    union all
    select 'elsa' as name, 130 as 'estimated', 162 as 'actual',  38 as diff 
) d
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT 1 AS chartgroup
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 
) c
```

Create your chart to group on name and the dummy group like in the image below

[image]

Your result will look like as the image below

[image]

Comment: I think there no other way to make it work in this case, but I always hope someone will have a better idea than mine